# How set `activeWhen/enabledWhen` command in eclipse RCP application according to project nature

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have eclipse RCP with Project nature RCPProjectNature_1 and RCPProjectNature_2.

I want to make some toolbar menu active only if project with nature RCPProjectNature_1 is open and once the project with RCPProjectNature_1 is closed toolbar menu should get disabled.

For Example
I have eclipse projects

1. RCPProject1 of project nature type RCPProjectNature_1
2. RCPProject2 of project nature type RCPProjectNature_2

The application has toolbar menu which is valid and should be enabled only if any project with  RCPProjectNature_1 is open. Or else it should be grayed out

How would I write expression in plugin.xml for the same?

Answer (score 3):

To test a single project use `<test>` on the `org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature` property.

An example from the org.eclipse.jdt.ui plugin:

```xml
<enabledWhen>
   <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
      <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
            value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature"/>
   </adapt>         
</enabledWhen>
```

When is testing for a Project object with the Java nature.

Update:

There is no way to iterate through all the projects in a normal command expression so you 
will have to write your own property tester using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point. This property tester can examine the workspace projects (the `IProject` objects).

Comment: It worked when I have two projects one with nature RCPProjectNature_1 closed and another is RCPProjectNature_2 open. at that time when I open the eclipse application it will disable the toolbar manu. However when I open the closed project then it does not enable the toolbar menu.

Comment: I have added expression for RCPProjectNature_1

Comment: It is not at all clear what your criteria for enablement are. Is this multiple projects? Do they have to be selected? What if there are more that two projects?

Comment: I have modified the question in detailed. I have multiple projects with multiple natures. ennoblement is depends upon openness of the project not selection.